# Unity 3D C# Script - my private member seems to just be alternating between 0 an the correct value

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a script in my unity application (called cubemove.cs).

**It has the private member:**

```
private float z_ref;
```

- Inside my `void Awake()` I have a line for initialization: `z_ref = (float) 0.0;`

**I have a button in my application set to run the following function onclick from cubemove.cs**

```
public void zeroZ()
{
    z_ref = (float) 45.0;
}
```

- My `void Update()` contains `Debug.Log("z_ref: " + z_ref.ToString());`

When I run the application and view the debugging output, first it's only printing `z_ref: 0`. This is expected as that is what I initialized the value to. Then when I hit the button in the application (which results in zeroZ() being executed), I *expect* it to now print 45. Instead it alternates between 45 and 0.

[Here is the image of the debug output after the button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUeuB.png)

- Prior to pressing the button it was all 0's.

My original program actually had more code when I first encountered this issue with my z_ref randomly changing (it wasn't fixed to 45, zeroZ() was a more complex function etc). However even after I changed my cubemove.cs file to the following code below, I still see this exact same behavior of z_ref alternating between 0 and the value it's supposed to be.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class cubemove : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    private float z_ref;

    void Awake()
    {
        z_ref = (float) 0.0;
    }
    void Start()
    {
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("z_ref: " + z_ref.ToString());
    }
    public void zeroZ()
    {
        z_ref = (float) 45.0;
    }
}
```

After `zeroZ()` is called there should no reason z_ref should ever show up as any value other then 45. What exactly is going on here?

In case it is relevant, my build target is android (the debug output image is from logcat).

Comment: Do you have any other objects with this script on it?

Comment: I guess there are 2 instances of `cubemove`.

Comment: @HeejaeKim is probably right. Log an instance ID or hash code to check if it's the same script.

Comment: Yes, there were in fact two instances of `cubemove`, silly me. The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, the issue was due to multiple instances of `cubemove` (it was associated with more then one gameobject, but I hadn't realized at the time).